# How can I reset my device's Google Cloud Messaging registration?

Tags: java, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I made a mistake in implementing gcm for my app in my phone, and it's not reciving any notifications now. The same app works perfectly(recives gcm notifications) in any other device. I need to unregister my phone from gcm what should I do?

Should I wait 7 days(default expiry time)?

Comment: Sorry, turns out, It was my mistake. I accidently mistyped a permission. really sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your app stores the Registration ID in `SharedPreferences`, and would register to GCM on launch if it doesn't find the Registration ID there. If that's the case, all your have to do is clear the application data (or, if that doesn't clear the `SharedPreferences`, uninstall and re-install the app). This would cause your app to register to GCM and get a valid registration ID.

> Should I wait 7 days(default expiry time)?

There is no such thing as expiry time for GCM Registration IDs. Some older versions of the GCM Client Demo (and perhaps the deprecated `GCMRegistrar` class too) would try to refresh the Registration ID every 7 days, but the reason for that was only to re-send the Registration ID to the server on a regular basis (to recover from the case in which the server's Registration IDs DB gets lost).

EDIT :

According to the [GoogleCloudMessaging class reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GoogleCloudMessaging.html#register%28java.lang.String...%29), if you are using a new sender ID to register to GCM, you must first call unregister :

> public String register (String... senderIds)
>
> Register the application for GCM and return the registration ID. You must call this once, when your application is installed, and send the returned registration ID to the server.
>
> Repeated calls to this method will return the original registration ID.
>
> **If you want to modify the list of senders, you must call unregister() first.**

Comment: I uninstalled the app, and created a new app with a different package name, under a different senderid in sever (dev dashboard). still not reciving any notification. it's been 2 days. what should I do?

This affects only the one device I started out with. The same app works ok on other devices.

Comment: @gen3 When you re-installed the app, did you get a new registration ID, or did the registration to GCM fail?

Comment: @gen3 I just remember something I read - if you register to GCM with a different sender ID, you should first un-register the old sender ID.

Answer (score 2):

You might try the following unregistration process for a single device (uninsalling the app and later reinstalling). (Note, this is from Google Cloud Messaging advanced documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html))

> **How unregistration works**
>
> An application can be automatically unregistered after it is
>   uninstalled from the device. However, this process does not happens
>   right away, as Android does not provide an uninstall callback. What
>   happens in this scenario is as follows:

1. The end user uninstalls the application.
2. The 3rd-party server sends a message to GCM server.
3. The GCM server sends the message to the device.
4. The GCM client receives the message and queries Package Manager about whether there are broadcast receivers configured to receive it, which returns false.
5. The GCM client informs the GCM server that the > application was uninstalled.
6. The GCM server marks the registration ID for deletion.
7. The 3rd-party server sends a message to GCM.
8. The GCM returns a NotRegistered error message to the 3rd-party server.
9. The 3rd-party deletes the registration ID.

> Note: The GCM client is the Google Cloud Messaging framework present on the device.
>
> Note that it might take a while for the registration ID be completely
>   removed from GCM. Thus it is possible that messages sent during step 7
>   above gets a valid message ID as response, even though the message
>   will not be delivered to the device. Eventually, the registration ID
>   will be removed and the server will get a NotRegistered error, without
>   any further action being required from the 3rd-party server (this
>   scenario happens frequently while an application is being developed
>   and tested).